# Continuous reading & writing using stdin and stdout in AT&T assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, stdout, stdin, att

I have a task to write a program in AT&T Assembly which can read and write part by part as long as you want sequence of bytes using Linux’s `stdin` and `stdout`.

It should be a Caesar cipher scrambler that changes only big Latin characters (A,B,C,D,…) one step forward (so like A to B, B to C, C to D, …, Z to A).

So like the program reads first part of the sequence, do operations to change letters leaving other characters untouched, writes the changed part to stdout, and reads next parts, and do everything again and again.

In the end it should work with files set to stdin and stdout by running the program by command

```
>./executable  >output.txt < input.txt
```

What I was able to write by now is the program that reads some amount of characters, do operations, prints output and ask for more. However if you put more characters in the input than the buf size it crashes.

Here’s the code:

```
SYSCALL32 = 0x80 

EXIT = 1 
ERR_CODE = 0

STDIN = 0 
READ = 3 

STDOUT = 1 
WRITE = 4  

BUF_SIZE = 80 

.data
textin: .space BUF_SIZE
textout: .space BUF_SIZE

.global _start
_start:
mov $READ, %eax
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $textin, %ecx
mov $BUF_SIZE, %edx

int $SYSCALL32 # reading 80 characters (buf_size) of std input

cmp $0, %eax 
je exit #if 0 characters read exit

xorl %esi, %esi #clering iterator for loop

loop:
mov textin(%esi), %al #copying 1 character from textin buf to work with

cmp $'\n', %al
je out 
cmp $'A', %al
jl skip
cmp $'Z', %al
jg skip
je takeCareOfZ

add $1, %al
jmp skip

takeCareOfZ:
mov $'A', %al

skip:
movb %al, textout(%esi)
incl %esi
jmp petla

out:
mov $WRITE, %eax
mov $STDOUT, %ebx
mov $textout, %ecx
mov $BUF_SIZE, %edx

int $SYSCALL32 #writing 80 characters to std output

jmp _start

exit:
mov $EXIT, %eax
mov $ERR_CODE, %ebx

int $SYSCALL32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of the program that removes the complexity associated with using a buffer of fixed size.

```
        .text
        .global _start
_start:
        # read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1)
        movl    $1, %edx    # size_t nbyte
        movl    $buf, %ecx  # void *buf
        movl    $0, %ebx    # int filedes
        movl    $3, %eax    # sys_read
        int     $0x80

        cmp     $1, %eax    
        jne     bye         # EOF or read() error

        cmp     $'A', (%ecx)
        jl      output      # *buf < 'A'

        cmp     $'Z', (%ecx)
        jg      output      # *buf > 'Z'
        je      z           # *buf == 'Z'

        incl    (%ecx)      # *buf >= 'A' && *buf < 'Z'
        jmp     output

z:
        movl    $'A', (%ecx)

output:
        # write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, 1)
        movl    $1, %ebx    # int filedes
        movl    $4, %eax    # sys_write
        int     $0x80
        jmp     _start

bye:
        # exit(0)
        movl    $0, %ebx    # int status
        movl    $1, %eax    # sys_exit
        int     $0x80

.data
buf:
        .byte 0
```

Sample run

```
$ gcc -nostdlib -m32 caesar.S -o caesar
$ ./caesar 
1234
1234
ABC1
BCD1
Z12BB
A12CC
```

Sample run using gdb, one instruction at a time.

[image: gdb caesar]

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I have some question to you if you don't mind to make everything clear for me:
1. Why after .byte there is 0, is it important or there could be anything in that usecase?
2. Why everytime there is something connected with %ecx it has to be in brackets? Like why  `cmp $'A', (%ecx)`, not `cmp $'A', %ecx`?

Comment: `buf` is a 1-byte buffer.  The initial value of 0 is never used and is irrelevant.   `%ecx` is equivalent to `buf`. `(%ecx)` is equivalent to `*buf`.

Comment: I have included an animation of how to use gdb to observe changes to registers and memory one instruction at a time.